# Parameter estimators of linear predictors

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, predictor

Suppose a linear predictor of the form $a + b'X$. To find estimators for a and b, should we minimize $E[Y-a-b'X]^2$ or $E[(Y-a-b'X)^2|X]$.

Former gives $\hat{a} = E[Y] - b'E[X]$ and latter gives $\hat{a} = E[Y|X] - b'X$

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want the former.

- You probably don't want your $\hat{a}$ to depend on the value of $X$.
- Even if you do want a dependence between the two, computing $E[Y|X]$ is something you would have to model again (possibly using a linear estimate) so you probably haven't gained much.